# How to build an Amazon QuickSight dashboard for CloudFront popular pages?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, web, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-quicksight

I have configured my CloudFront to log all access and save it to an S3 bucket.
What is the best way to visualize the most popular pages for my website using AWS native tools like QuickSight?
(I don't need to embed this data anywhere. Simply view what pages are the most popular for my website hosted via CloudFront.)

Comment: I voted to close this question because there are usually hundreds of ways to implement a feature; too many to enumerate here. Furthermore, a full answer to any one of them could require many pages or even a full book. Rather than asking for an approach, [edit] your question to focus on a more specific problem you encounter when you actually try to implement it yourself.

Comment: There may be "hundreds" of ways to achieve this, but there are limited ways to get it all done _natively_ on AWS.

Comment: You can write whatever app you want and host it natively on an EC2 instance of AWS. Limiting yourself to just AWS solutions isn't a big limitation at all here.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have configured your CloudFront to log all access and save it to an S3 bucket, the best way is to create visuals with the data stored in the S3 bucket so that you can visualize your most popular pages of CloudFront for your website using QuickSight as it is continually updating in S3.

Firstly, you need to create a manifest file for data files in S3 and then create a dataset from it respectively.[1][2]
On the Analysis page, the datasets that were created above were used to create the visuals.[3]
You can use different sheets to fetch data from different datasets that were created earlier in order to visualize the data.
Then you can publish a dashboard for created visual and arrange visuals in it.[4][5]
I have also shared a couple of links to the documentation for your easy and quick reference.

References:

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/create-a-data-set-s3.html

[2] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/supported-manifest-file-format.html

[3] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/adding-a-data-set-to-an-analysis.html

[4] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/creating-a-dashboard.html

[5] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/visualizing-data-dashboards.html

Comment: This answer assumes that your log data is less than 1000 files and the total volume of data is less than your subscription to QuickSight allows. Otherwise, you will have to employ Glue and Athena to extract the data for QuickSight dashboard.

Comment: If you need to process more than 1000 files, checkout my blog on this topic: https://blog.richiebartlett.com/2022/0809/Work_仕事/How-to-build-QuickSight-dashboard-for-CloudFront-website.html